# SQL query flatten data of 1-many relationship table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

User table

```
id    | emailAddress
1       user@test.com
2       user2@test.com
```

Device table

```
 uuid   | user_id
 xyz     1
 abc     1
 zzz     1
 a11     2
 g222    2
```

I want to flatten the result of related device table in a column. Here's my attempt using a subquery.

```
SELECT id, emailAddress, (
    SELECT uuid FROM device 
    WHERE user_id = user.id
) AS devices 
FROM user;
```

I want my result output to be like this.

```
1, user@test.com  xyz, abc, zzz
2, user2@test.com a112, g222
```

**But I also want to clear my objective perhaps for a lateral approach to achieve what I want, Ultimately I want to populate this UserBean in my Java Code.** i.e. Get all Users and each user with a list of devices.

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String emailAddress;
    private ArrayList<DeviceBean> devices = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... some getter setters etc.
}

public class DeviceBean {
    private String uuid;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Use a join and a consistent ordering, and process repeating records as devices belonging to the same user.

Comment: ok, you're suggesting to iterate records one by one in java loop?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel although I got the answer but at the end iteration is better, reason, I needed id of each device within the list as well, not just list of uuids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`GROUP_CONCAT`** to concatenate the `uuid` column values group by `id` and `emailAddress`.

**Query**

```
select t1.`id`, t1.`emailAddress`,
group_concat(t2.`uuid`)
from `users` t1
join `devices` t2
on t1.`id` = t2.`user_id`
group by t1.`id`, t1.`emailAddress`;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d6ef0/1)**

Comment: i used group by id only, it works, but do you see areas where it won't work. wondering why did you add emailAddress to the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten the result you so use [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/). You should join your tables as shown below:

```
SELECT A.id, A.emailAddress, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.uuid ORDER BY B.uuid SEPARATOR ',') AS devices 
FROM `user` A LEFT JOIN device B
ON A.id=B.user_id
GROUP BY A.id, A.emailAddress;
```

**See [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a772b3/1) on SQL Fiddle.**